# Jquery mouseenter mouseleave not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move the title of wp plugin from thumbnails when the mouse hover and place these in another div on top via this script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".caption").mouseenter(function() {

    $(".captiondiv").html("");

    var str = $(".caption-title:visible").text();

    $(".captiondiv").prepend(str);

  }).mouseleave(function() {

    $(".captiondiv").html("");

  });
});
```

It work well, when I hover slowly on each thumbnails, the caption is showing correctly on the top left video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DKDq0RNJM4&feature=youtu.be

If I hover quickly the script show me bad captions, It leaves the previous caption and adds the new :(

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAK0LhkwUbI&feature=youtu.be

I'm really lost! please help!

Best regards!

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: It is a plugin that is installed on wp,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `prepend` if you want to replace entire title.
You can just use `$(".captiondiv").html(str);`

**EDIT**
the problem was that element `(".caption-title:visible")` had multiple values. It was solved using `$(this)` element to get the wanted element.

```
var str = $(this).find(".caption-title:visible").text();
$(".captiondiv").html(str);
```

Comment: I tried with html() but is not working, same problem :(

Comment: But, why the problem appears when I hover queckly ?

Comment: maybe the selector `$(".jig-caption-title:visible")` returns more than an element, because there is a transition from colorful to grayscale. I cannot determine without the code.
`console.log($(".jig-caption-title:visible"));` will help you find the error.

Comment: yes this is the probleme, but how i can show only the caption of the active thumbnails without :visible ? because when i remove visible the script show me all the captions, the plugin use this : <div class="caption" style="display: none;"><div class="caption-title">11</div></div>

Comment: try `var str = $(this).find(".jig-caption-title:visible").text(); $(".caption-perso").html(str);` to refer only to the mouse enter element. It works if `jig-caption-title` is child of `.jig-caption`

Comment: You are a genius Dimitis!! You save my life :) it work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("ul li img").hover(
    function(){
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        $("strong").html(alt);
    },
    function(){
        $("strong").html("");
    }
);
```

```css
ul{
    list-style-type:none
}
ul li{
    float:left  
}
ul li img{
    /* grayscale effect */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
       -moz-filter: grayscale(1); 
         -o-filter: grayscale(1); 
        -ms-filter: grayscale(1); 
            filter: grayscale(1);
}
ul li img:hover{
    /* clear grayscale effect */
    -webkit-filter: none; 
       -moz-filter: none; 
         -o-filter: none; 
        -ms-filter: none; 
            filter: none;
    /* set 3s animate */
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Title:</span>
<strong></strong>

<ul>
    <li><img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blackblue/128/iPhoto.png' alt='1'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/DarkGlass_Reworked/128x128/apps/sodipodi.png' alt='2'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IS_CMS/128/image.png' alt='3'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flatforlinux/128/7-Image%20capture.png' alt='4'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fs-icons-ubuntu-by-franksouza-/128/image-png.png' alt='5'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/apps/synfig_icon.png' alt='6'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/128x128/filesystems/folder_image.png' alt='7'></li>
    <li><img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oxygen/128x128/mimetypes/image-png.png' alt='8'></li>
</ul>
```

---

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/Lonz47bh/)

Comment: Thank you ! but the plugin that i want to modifie use <div> to group thumbnails instead <ul>,it may be the problem ?

Comment: It is not a problem. This is only a preview. You have a problem with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See how I solved it myself. I used `hover`, and gave him two functions. The first function is like `mouseenter`, the second is like `mouseleave`.

Comment: I had same problem with hover too :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'prepend' method use .html() method to set the content of the element.

Comment: How about Stop() function ?

Comment: stop() function is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) on that element is immediately stopped.
here we want to set the data of an element.
if possible could you please share the code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".jig-caption").mouseenter(function() {

    var str = $(".jig-caption-title:visible").text();

    $(".caption-perso").html(str);

  }).mouseleave(function() {

    $(".caption-perso").html("");

  });

});
```